# PATH has invalid characters

Tags: macos, bash, path

I was fiddling with my PATH on my mac because home-brew wasn't working. My path could be broken down into three versions:

Clean path is the most ideal path, since I don't use Pebble's SDK anymore. Nasty path is the original, messed up path. Old path is nasty path with the errors removed

```
 Nasty path

   /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/peterkaminski/anaconda/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0- BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/apache-ant-1.9.3


Clean path

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/peterkaminski/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/apache-ant-1.9.3


OLD PATH


/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/peterkaminski/anaconda/bin:“/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/apache-ant-1.9.3/bin:??
```

My ~/.bash_profile for the nasty path looks like this: (Forgive me, I've been fooling with it for about an hour trying to fix it, so it looks terrible)

```
JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
ANT_HOME="/Users/peterkaminski/apache-ant-1.9.3"
LES_SDK="/Users/peterkaminski/Lexmark"


export PATH=~/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME
export ANT_HOME
export LES_SDK

PATH=“/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$LES_SDK”
export PATH




# added by Anaconda 2.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/peterkaminski/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

#PATH=“/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$LES_SDK”
#export PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-06-24_at_10:32:22
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-06-24_at_10:32:22: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
# export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-09-07_at_22:49:58
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-09-07_at_22:49:58: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


##
# Your previous /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/peterkaminski/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-09-24_at_23:53:49
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-09-24_at_23:53:49: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
#export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

How do I go about modifying the path to get it back to a default state? Or do you notice any glaring bugs? I'm not sure what would bring about the addition of a " and the bin:??.

Comment: There is a space character in your NASTY PATH `/Users/peterkaminski /anaconda/bin` and a `"` in your OLD PATH `“/Users/peterkaminski/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA5/bin` Which one are you exactly trying to fix?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: the four line `export PATH=.. ` are of no use, PATH variable is overwritten.

Comment: You have curly quotes in your .bash_profile(?) which suggest you attempted to edit the file with a incompatible editor.

Comment: @Archemar Each of those ends with `:$PATH`, so the result is to prepend a directory to the path. (Oh, you are referring to the assignment that follows those four, that *doesn't* include `$PATH` in the value.)

Comment: yes final PATH= statement do not take previous value of $PATH.